# How do werewolves cope with integration into human society with tough ban on transformation?

Tags: law, social-norms, werewolf

In my world werewolves are humans but would transform into part man part wolf when they stares at round and shiny object such as a full moon, the humans knew about it and even extended their welcome but there is a catch: no transformation is allowed and the penalty is death by firing squad.

Now the issues are humans enjoy living with werewolves and it's no secret provided they don't transform in the presence of people. All it takes is a single complain and the firing squad is called in, no trial no excuse no matter how young the culprit. Actually majority of the public don't give a shit when they saw them transform but then there is always someone who seemingly detest their kind and would constantly jump on the opportunity to get rid of them, so I wonder how do these werewolves cope with such an unforgiving society?

Btw studies show that only staring at shiny and round shaped object as big as a dime for 30 seconds is enough to trigger the transformation in werewolves. Also note that the werewolves are immigrants from some nasty places where conflicts and famines are the norm!

Set in the modern time as I am curious if technology can help to tackle prejudice that has span eons and then to make matters worse any human who tries to cover up the incident will be facing a jail term or a hefty fine, or both.

We can assume shiny is anything that gives off or reflect light that measures above 0.1 lux, as for the law I am sure we have heard even more ridiculous one before.

Comment: This needs improvements. Examples. Transformation is unclear. Do we consider the moon shiny? What does shiny mean? How about car lights? Shiny does not mean emitting light. Are werewolves old or new in the world? immigrated from where? Do all of them lack a citizenship in all places? Then the laws. Very odd. How can they execute a citizen for the mere transformation and not hurting people? Certainly weird and terrifying to see it. But I'm fairly certain all laws don't make it a crime to merely transform into anything. Only hurting others. Also false reports? Overall needs to be clear

Comment: @Seallussus: edited, see the footnote ;D

Comment: There are too many naughty children with polished coins in your world (unless the people are very different from ours). It's difficult to imagine how things could work-out in any way but tragically for the werewolves.

Comment: This system does not work. Lets say I accuse you of transformation. You arent a werewolf, but there's no judicial system that verifies that it is true or not, just a firing squad who kills whoever you point at. If you solve that problem then you have some kind of jews system where they are constantly hounded (heh) by the risk of being executed for something someone else might force on you (say hanging a street full of round shiny objects, say lamps). Secrecy about being a werewolf is the protection you need, but does not protect against vindictive people making area's impassable.

Comment: Does the transformation still apply through media e.g. looking at a picture of the moon or watching a documentary about it on TV?

Comment: "All it takes is a single complain and the firing squad is called in, no trial no excuse no matter how young the culprit." - this is a fascist dystopia, not just for the werewolves, but for everybody. it doesn't matter how the werewolves would integrate. and they would do everything they could to prevent contact - famine is preferable to fascism.

Answer (score 2):

### Any solution that differentiates the werewolf from the average person is a death sentence

> Actually majority of the public don't give a shit when they saw them transform but then there is always someone who seemingly detest their kind and would constantly jump on the opportunity to get rid of them

> the firing squad is called in, no trial no excuse no matter how young the culprit

> any human who tries to cover up the incident will be facing a jail term or a hefty fine, or both

Anything that shows that someone is or might be a werewolf will immediately cause someone to false report them and get them killed. Even if there are a few people who don't want to false report them, if the majority of people can just claim they are covering it up, they might get fined. Since there is no trial, the werewolf will be killed, and anyone defending the werewolf will be hit with a fine or jail time.

If there is no way to determine if someone is a werewolf before they die then it is possible to kill anyone with a false report as long as you are ok with being charged with false reporting. If there is no way to check if someone is a werewolf before or after death then this can be used to arbitrarily kill anyone with no consequences.

If there is a way to know if someone is a werewolf before killing them then you can still use this to arbitrarily throw people into jail. Just claim you saw a werewolf transform in front of you and your target. So long as you can get yourself and a werewolf into proximity of your target they will probably be hit with the fine. Normally the werewolf would make it two words against one, but there is no trail, so that loose end is taken care of. So long as there are no witnesses who are not in on your ploy you have a high chance of success, and multiple witnesses in your employ would help your case.

### Wear sunglasses

Wearing sunglasses will bring most bright circles down to below 0.1 lux, just make sure you don't stare at the sun. Many people wear sunglasses, and while you may end up being the weird guy who wears sunglasses everywhere, that is better than death. the important thing is that if someone checks your sunglasses, they are actually sunglasses, so that won't mark you as a werewolf.

driving is hard, since traffic lights are bright circles, but you could drive with something just above eye level to block the sun, that instead blocks out the traffic lights. Check the lights periodically if you are the first car in line, or approaching an intersection, otherwise just watch the car in front of you.

Just pretend to not be a werewolf, close your eyes if you see a bright circle and always have a few fashionable pairs of sunglasses.

Comment: On my commute the sun is low throughout the autumn and winter, shining directly into my eyes for extended periods of time. Sunglasses and the sunshade dont really help. This is a massive problem as during certain times werewolves simply cannot travel in the direction of the equator for fear of transformation.

Answer (score 1):

**pixelate contact lens/glass**

-now you can see the world in 32/64/128-bits.

-studies show 420% reduced to werewolves public execution in the past 10 years.

at reachable price 169$, and we throw in life insurance offer as well.

or maybe typical light-reduced glass to cut out that 'shiny 'from said rule 'round and shiny', extend gracing period from 30 sec to like 5-10 mins (long enough to avoid eye contact with the object)